# styleUrls is not applied in angular

Tags: angular

I have a component like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-main',
  templateUrl: './header-main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['header-main.component.less']
})
export class HeaderMainComponent implements OnInit {

  searchValue: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In my template there is a div

```
<mat-form-field class="header_search">
```

with in the less file

```
.header_search {
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: red;
}
```

but the style is not applied.... why ?

Comment: It should work, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eo3hgr?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html).

Comment: actually I just see that it does work, but I can't edit the mat-tab css that are inside the component.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eo3hgr-3k3qtz

Answer (score 2):

In order to style the content of a child component, you can use the [`::ng-deep`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) shadow-piercing descendant combinator:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label { 
  transform: skew(20deg);
  ...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eo3hgr-f2pruh?file=app/form-field-overview-example.less) for a demo.

---

An alternative is to turn off the [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) of the component:

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eo3hgr-qkztbn?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts) for a demo.